# Django filtering doesn't work with float field

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to get some records from the MySQL database but it seems that filtering by float field doesn't work. When I filter just by `user_id` I receive all records but when I add the `value` clause just got *DoesNotExist* exception.

I have the following models and query:

```py
class Record(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    value = models.FloatField()

class User(models.Model):
    value = models.FloatField()
```

```py
Record.objects.get(
    user_id=user.id,
    value=user.value
)
```

`user.value` variable in the python code is `0.4` (`float`). The `value` column in the database is type `float unsigned` and its value is `0.4`.

I guess it's something because of the nature of float type but what is the right way to filter by float value using Django models?

Comment: Have you tried `filter` instead of `get`?

Comment: @itsmehemant7, yes, this doesn't help

Comment: one trick could be...you can store float as string in charField. In this case, you just have to convert the string to float (& vice-versa) before saving and after retrieving data from DB

Comment: @itsmehemant7 this will work probably but I hope that there is a more elegant way to handle this case with Django.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with how Python represents floating point values (Django's FloatField translates to Python's float and Django's DecimalField maps to Python's decimal; see https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

The distinction is that floats are not exact due to the way they are represented on your computer; the decimal type seeks to address some of these shortcomings (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#floatfield-vs-decimalfield).

Given your situation of attempting to retrieve a float through an exact match, you have two options:

Change the value type on User and Record to DecimalField (value = models)

DecimalField(number of digits=5, number of places=2, null=True)

You can query a range of values if you want to maintain the type as a FloatField.

Comment: I changed it to `models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)` but the result is the same